# ViewerSorter - eclipse.SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Есть таблица , в ней несколько колонок.

При загрузке таблица заполняется строчками с данными. Тут все работает корректно.
Как можно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на нужную мне колонку вызывался нужный мне Sorter ? 
Т.е. я нажал на колонку дату - она обновилась согласно моим правилам сравнения.

На данный момент работает только при загрузке. 
П.С. как можно сделать чтобы при первом нажатии s1.compareTo(s2), а при втором s2.compare(s1) - т.е. снизу вверх, и сверху вниз.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, там на каждый столб надо вешать listener ,
например:

```
TableColumn         nameOfTable.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("по дефолту");
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Меня выбрали");
        }

    });
```